# decrement of a number in filename with cmd on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, decrement

I have a bunch of files:

```
CAR_003.dat
CAR_003.obj
CAR_004_prev0.png
CAR_004_prev1.png
CAR_004_tex0.tga
```

I need to rename them to:

```
CAR_002.dat
CAR_002.obj
CAR_003_prev0.png
CAR_003_prev1.png
CAR_003_tex0.tga
```

how I can do this with cmd on windows in a batch?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please [edit] your post and provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Also take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the following batch in the directory you want. 
It will rename everything in the tree.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /R %%f in (CAR*) DO (
  FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%m in ('%%~nxf') do (
    SET      filePath=%%~dpf
    SET    filePrefix=%%m_
    SET /a fileNumber=1%%~nn-1001
    SET    fileNumber=000!fileNumber!
    SET    fileNumber=!fileNumber:~-3!
    SET    filePosfix=%%~no
    SET       fileExt=%%~xf
    IF [!filePosfix!] EQU [] ( 
      SET    fileRest=%%~xf
    ) ELSE ( 
      SET    fileRest=_!filePosfix!!fileExt!
    )
    REM ECHO %%f
    REM ECHO !filePath!!filePrefix!!fileNumber!!fileRest!
    REM ECHO ~~~~~~~
    MOVE "%%f" "!filePath!!filePrefix!!fileNumber!!fileRest!"
  )
)
```

Comment: I don't understand why StackOverflow allows you to answer questions before you can even comment...

Comment: Your code will fail if the zero filled number is 008 or 009. This is clearly stated in the help file for the set command. I assume Microsoft put that in the help file for people who do not understand the difference between decimal and octal.

Comment: I make the code based on the guy's example. The chat is here for that, if he doesn't say anything I suppose it's ok for what he was aiming for. .. I have now fixed octal conversion up to 999... But he can come here now and say it doesn't work with 1000, then I will fix again to 1000009999-1000000001? hehe

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. it says: Files moved: 0. Invalid number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021). System cannot find the path specified. for every file. I have a lot of files in a single folder but number after CAR_ is always between 001-688. there's not other numbers except the ones from the example after suffixes 'prev' and 'tex'. number after CAR_ is always made of 3 digits.

Comment: @AntonShmetelko you shouldn't be getting that error if you are using the most updated version of the code. The new code works just fine.  I have verified it.

Comment: @Squashman, I'm getting that error. I tried one more time. I have 6580 files in the folder and none of them were renamed. everything is in a same folder. Also, I give _process.cmd name to the script if that matter.

Comment: @AntonShmetelko if you are getting that error with the new code then the file names you provided in your question are not in the same format as what is on your computer. The code is based on the 5 file name examples you provided in your question.  Works perfectly fine.

Comment: There are two additional bugs in the code. If there were also any underscores or periods in folder names you would have received that error.  I have fixed that bug in the code.  The other bug is in regards to whether there are one or two underscores in the actual file name. The file will get renamed incorrectly when there is only one underscore in the original file name.  I will let @Zano fix that one for you.

Comment: @Squashman, thanks! looks like it does the job. But as you said there's bug with a single underscore in the name — it turns CAR_001.dat into CAR_001_dat.

Comment: I didn't find any easy way to do this. This is ok for the example files. I won't edit anymore >:(